# Trying ty change text in EditText within GridLayout

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my first app which is supposed to be a Sudoku-solver. 
I think I'm almost there but have one problem I've tried to solve for hours now and therefore I'm reaching out to you. 
I have a GridLayout with 81 TextBox. I have no problem transfer numbers from the 81 TextBox'es to a 9*9 matrix using:

```
private void writeToNbrs() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
        int temp;
        try {
            temp = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) layout.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString());
        } catch(Exception e){
            temp = 0;
        }
        int a = i/9;
        int row = a;
        int col = i%9;
        nbrs[row][col] = temp;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I want to transfer numbers from the matrix to the TextBoxes for this I use the following code:

```
private void writeToText(){
    for(int row = 0; row<9; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col<9; col++){
            int temp = nbrs[row][col];
            int i = row*9+col;
            ((EditText)layout.getChildAt(i)).setText(temp);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm not very familiar with the debugger but I've tried to used it and I now understand that it crashes at:

```
((EditText)layout.getChildAt(i)).setText(temp);
```

during the first iteration.
Why is this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code like this ,

```
((EditText)layout.getChildAt(i)).setText(temp+"");
```

Other wise it will look for resource id and will crash .

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it. But why?? Makes no sense to me

Comment: In android you can use string resource id (int) instead of actual string .Please accept answer if it helps you-

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.valueOf(temp)` to convert `temp` to `String`

**Try this:**

```
((EditText)layout.getChildAt(i)).setText(String.valueOf(temp));
```